# differential privacy over a normal vector

Tags: differential-privacy

We're given a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ whose coordinates where sampled from a known normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.

How should I send this vector while maintaining (local) differential privacy? with some sensitivity over its $\ell_2$ norm (i.e., two close vectors should not be distinguishable). Is there a way to take the fact that we know the source distribution into account?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify how addition or removal of an individual effect your vector?

Comment: The machanism should make nearby vectors \epsilon - indistinguishable. So instead of the regular missing point in the dataset formulation the changed dataset(vector) is any other vector "nearby" (given an l2 bound on the distance)